# Complex responsive HTML layout using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, handlebars.js

I have a requirement to create a News section on a webpage (it's SharePoint, but that's probably not terribly relevant) which looks something like the image below.

My issue is that HTML will be dynamically generated from a list of the news items, so the code for each item will be the same - ie. I don't think I can add code to differentiate between the left hand column item and the right  hand column items.

The code is formatted with handlebars.js, but the lack of logic there seems to prevent me from doing it there?

So using a simple {{#each items}} in the handlebars, I end up with something like this:

```html
<div class="newsContainer">
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link1"><img src="image1"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link1">Headline 1</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link2"><img src="image2"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link2">Headline 2</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link3"><img src="image3"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link3">Headline 3</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link4"><img src="image4"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link4">Headline 4</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my challenge is to create the layout below from the code above using either just CSS, or CSS and JavaScript.

I've made limited progress with ":first-of-type", but I'm wondering if something like FlexBox may be another option?

[image: Example of required layout]

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you change the template to that the first item in `items`, and place that in your left column, and iterate over the remaining items for the right column?

Comment: Flexbox would *not* really be ideal here...CSS-Grid would offer better opportunities.

Comment: What is the browser support you need to have?

Comment: Simple old floating can do the trick here as well … simply float the first item to the left, and all following ones to the right, plus `clear:right` on those … add in appropriate widths, and basically done.

Comment: Thanks everyone - It's working now using Red's solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archieve the desired layout by using floating divs. I wrote a little example for you.

I didn't edit any of the `HTML` you provided. So you could just *copy* and *paste* the `CSS` from below.

See below snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 This is a clearfix. Floated divs have to be cleared, else the layout will mess up
*/
.newsContainer::before,
.newsContainer::after,
.newsContainer .newsItem::before,
.newsContainer .newsItem::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem {
  float: left;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem:first-child {
  width: 50%;
}

/** 
  Margin-left 5% acts as spacing
  Put all divs near the first child, except :first-child using CSS :not() selector
*/
.newsContainer .newsItem:not(:first-child) {
  width: 45%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

/** 
  Overwrite above CSS, now set float right on the 4th and 5th divs. You can add
  more divs `.newsItem:nth-child(6) ... etc` if more divs are present.
  Set margin left value same as .newsContainer .newsItem:first-child width
*/
.newsContainer .newsItem:nth-child(5) {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

/**
 This is just for responive images
*/
.newsContainer .newsItem img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem .newsTitle > a,
.newsContainer .newsItem .newsSummary {
  color: #969696;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem .newsTitle > a {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem .newsSummary {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem > div {
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.newsContainer .newsItem:not(:first-child) > * {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsContainer">
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x500"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link1">Headline 1</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link2">Headline 2</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link3">Headline 3</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link4">Headline 4</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="newsItem">
    <a href="link4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/></a>
    <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link4">Headline 5</a></div>
    <div class="newsSummary">Summary 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is close, but it relies on the main (left column) image file being bigger than the others. Mine will all be the same size at source, so will also need to be resized in the CSS.

Comment: Just play with the provided snippet. In the end you will get what you want to archieve.

Comment: Yep, I'm almost there now - it's working standalone just by adding .newsContainer .newsItem:first-child {width: 50%;} .newsContainer .newsItem:not(:first-child) {width: 25%;} - now I just need to work on resolving some CSS conflicts because the actual code is surrounded by other stuff which seems to be breaking it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Dave No problem, glad I could he helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own columnar layout to achieve this:

```css
.newsContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsContainer">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="newsItem">
      <a href="link1"><img src="image1" /></a>
      <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link1">Headline 1</a></div>
      <div class="newsSummary">Summary 1</div>
    </div>
  </div><!--End Col 1-->

  <div class="col">
    <div class="newsItem">
      <a href="link2"><img src="image2" /></a>
      <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link2">Headline 2</a></div>
      <div class="newsSummary">Summary 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsItem">
      <a href="link3"><img src="image3" /></a>
      <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link3">Headline 3</a></div>
      <div class="newsSummary">Summary 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="newsItem">
      <a href="link4"><img src="image4" /></a>
      <div class="newsTitle"><a href="link4">Headline 4</a></div>
      <div class="newsSummary">Summary 4</div>
    </div>

  </div><!--End Col 2-->
</div>
```